# When is an endpoint bundle-aware and when not?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

From
Link: *[www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcbundlepolicy](http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcbundlepolicy)*
Content: *4.2.5 RTCBundlePolicy Enum*

"If the remote endpoint is bundle-aware, all media tracks and data channels are bundled onto the same transport."

**When is an endpoint bundle-aware and when not? And what does bundle-aware means?**

Answer (score 2):

To establish a p2p connection, WebRTC will allocate and do STUN network checks on up to 3 ports (multiplied by ways they can be reached) on either end, and as they're discovered (which takes time), ask JS to trickle-exchange info on each of these "ICE candidates" across a signaling channel, once for video, once for audio, and once for data (if you have it).

WebRTC does this mostly to support connecting to non-browser legacy devices, because all modern browsers support [BUNDLE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8843), which is when all but one candidate end up being thrown away, and all media gets bundled over that single port.

WebRTC even has a `"max-compat"` mode that goes even further, allocating a port for *each piece of media*, just in case the other endpoint is really old.

WebRTC doesn't know the other endpoint is a browser until it receives an "answer" from it, but if you know,  you can specify `"max-bundle"` and save a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: I see, so old browsers aren't bundle-aware. Can you please, give some examples of non-bundle-aware devices [non-browser]?

Comment: Old equipment like VoiP gateways and routers I suppose. I wouldn't worry about them unless you have one.  I wouldn't worry about old browsers either, as BUNDLE likely predates reliable WebRTC.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot jib. Will use "max-bundle" and see how it goes.